# Read local CSV with relative path in ReactJS

Tags: csv, reactjs, papaparse

With `reactjs` (in Meteor) I would like to read a local csv file with a relative path and loop over it's rows:

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';
var csvfile = "../../../data.csv";
Papa.parse(csvfile, {
  step: function (row) {
    console.log("Row:", row.data);
  },
});
```

This returns

> Row: [ [ '../../../data.csv' ] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your library expect JSON, whereas you specified a path.

You should read the JSON from your file using fs and then pass that to the parse method.

```
fs.readFile(csvFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    Papa.parse(data, {
     step: function (row) {
      console.log("Row:", row.data);
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: FileReaderSync is not defined`

Comment: This is NodeJS server

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `download` config flag when using a file instead of a string as input. From the [config documentation](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config):

> If true, this indicates that the string you passed as the first
> argument to parse() is actually a URL from which to download a file
> and parse its contents.

```
import csvFile from '../../data/my-csv-file.csv'

Papa.parse(csvFile, {
    download: true,
    complete: function (input) {
         const records = input.data;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simon Raes' answer helped the most. Here's a complete React example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { readString } from 'react-papaparse';
import siteListCSV from './example.csv';

const papaConfig = {
  complete: (results, file) => {
    console.log('Parsing complete:', results, file);
  },
  download: true,
  error: (error, file) => {
    console.log('Error while parsing:', error, file);
  },
};
readString(siteListCSV, papaConfig);

function App() {
  return (
    <h1>Check the console</h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This gives me a "unable to resolve module error" on the "import siteListCSV from './example.csv' " and says none of the files exist, even though my file is there. Thanks for the help